# Physical Explanation of Quantum Mechanics Notation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, notation

**CLARIFICATION:** I just don't understand what the notations below mean and how to use them.

=============

I just started taking QM, and the new notation is quite confusing.  While the math makes a nominal amount of sense during class lectures, I would find it much more satisfying to actually understand what the math means (and this would also assist in learning what operations and manipulations I need to do in a given situation).  Currently, I'm lost when I try doing any homework.

So, what are the physical interpretations of the following (if they exist):

1. $\left| \psi \right\rangle$
2. $\left\langle \psi \right|$
3. $\left| \psi \right\rangle\left\langle \psi \right|$
4. $\left\langle \psi | \psi \right\rangle$

Comment: Physical interpretations?? What do you want to mean by that? They are vectors with infinite basis. Do want to hear more?

Comment: @user36790 not necessarily, the basis may be finite. Counter example: a two-level system.

Comment: I don't understand the confusion or the downvotes. It seems like a straightforward question. The answer isn't always straightforward, but there is an answer. If it's silly to ask what the physical interpretation of a theory is, then of what use is the theory?

Comment: @Bronius: The OP said he can brute force his way trough the math but he also claims that he is lost when he is trying to do his homework, so at least one of the two is a lie. He is lost because he didn't do his homework for the first lesson. Will it help him if we say that these are notations of state vectors? Can we expect him to know what a dual space is? What's the interpretation of a wavefunction? Nothing. Is that going to help him with his homework?

Comment: @CuriousOne: Well said. Regarding the interpretation, there can be many. Now why are column matrices used? It can be directly traced back to the economics where each element defines each sector of industrialisation, or each element can define the number of fruits in a variety of fruits in a carton. In QM, each ket can represent each state of  an ammonia molecule; you can't end in a single paragraph of its use. Definitely, OP has not done sufficient research effort. Downvote, thus.

Comment: @CuriousOne: sorry about the contradiction, I think I've removed it.  The main point is, I don't know what most of these things actually mean in the real world, and so trying to apply them to solve problems in that may occur in the real world is quite challenging.

Comment: If you think there is no physical interpretation of a wavefunction, we must either disagree about what the wavefunction is, or what "physical interpretation" means.

Comment: @BenSandeen: The bras and kets are just symbols. They don't mean anything other than as tools to calculate the state evolution of a quantum system. We can't measure them. We can measure expectation values of their products (including some linear operators that we stick between them). Expectation value is often denoted with angular brackets, the notation reminds us that the product can be an expectation value. The theory is linear, so the product is a product on linear spaces. If the kets are vectors in function space, then the bras are linear functionals.

Comment: @BenSandeen: I am an experimentalist, I am using the only interpretation allowed in physics: that of a meaningful physical object needing a representation in form of a physical machine that can approximate it. One can't approximate wave functions with any physical machine, one can only prepare states (up to a complex phase factor) and measure expectation values. There is nothing wrong with that. In classical mechanics one also can't measure absolute velocities, i.e. CM is degenerate with respect to inertial systems and transformations between them. QM is simply degenerate in a different way.

Comment: And yet surely you wouldn't claim that velocity has **no physical interpretation**. You would explain the physical interpretation, and note the complexities. But...it's probably time to let this drop, as the comments section is getting a bit long.

Comment: @Bronius: Absolute velocity has absolutely no meaningful physical interpretation. We are trying very hard to teach that in high school, if I remember correctly. Proper mathematical analyses of CM are therefor putting velocity in a tangent space, rather than a coordinate space. One could, and probably should, teach CM as a theory that lives on a tangent bundle on a (trivial) manifold. That way students would learn that the everyday "interpretation" of velocity is wrong and the transfer of that knowledge to general relativity would be next to trivial.

Comment: @Bronius: The idea that somehow mathematically useful quantities in physics always have to have a strict interpretation is the source of many fruitless and unnecessary discussion. They don't. One can use quantities in theories that are not representable by experiments and be perfectly happy, as long as one knows that they are not. There is, of course, an entire universe of quantum mystics who still don't understand this lesson that has been around since Galileo's time and who are still trying to measure "the wave function".

Comment: your whole question needs a long answer ... which is in the course and in the compact wiki page on "Bra–ket notation"

Comment: What's unclear about my question?  Why is it on hold?  I simply don't understand what some quantum mechanical notations mean and how they're used; is it that damn hard and risky to reach out for help here?

Comment: @BenSandeen Read Nielsen and Chuang: "Quantum Computation and Quantum Information".

Answer (score 3):

We can talk about what the notation **represents**. Terms I introduce will be italicised. For 1, the *ket* $\left|\psi\right\rangle$ represents the state of a physical system. Quantum mechanics claims these are elements of a *vector space*. So far, it's all physical. However, everything afterwards will abstract from that.

For 2 and 4, the *bra* $\left\langle\psi\right|$ represents the *linear map* $L$ from such states to complex numbers satisfying $\left|L\left|\phi\right\rangle\right|\leq L\left|\psi\right\rangle\in\left[0,\,\infty\right]$. For physical states we in fact impose $\left\langle\psi|\psi\right\rangle =1$. Computing an inner product is analogous to defining coordinates of points in space. (In fact, doing that can be written in this *bra-ket formalism*, but the usual notation on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is much easier.) If you know the axioms that define a vector space, you'll notice the set of bras is a vector space (as is the set of kets). It's called the *dual space* of the vector space of kets. In the bra-ket formalism, the two vectors in a "dot product" are thought of as different types of mathematical object; in a less pedantic formalism, the bras are just functions that take the dot product with a fixed vector.

The complex numbers obtained from bras are called *inner products*. For a generalisation of 3, the *outer product* $\left|\psi\right\rangle \left\langle\Psi\right|$ denotes the linear map $M$ satisfying $\left\langle\phi\right|M\left|\Phi\right\rangle=\left\langle\phi|\psi\right\rangle \left\langle\Psi|\Phi\right\rangle$. Note this is two inner products multiplied together, so $M$ is a map from a bra and a ket to a complex number. (In layman's terms, it's a matrix.) It's linear in the ket and *antilinear* in the bra, so it's called a *sesquilinear map*.

Answer (score 3):

I think the easiest way to think about these objects is as follows:

1. $|\psi\rangle$ is your physical state
2. Your physical state comes with a machine (its *dual*) $\langle \psi |$, which when applied to any other physical state $|\phi \rangle$, spits out the overlap $\langle \psi | \phi \rangle$ between your state and $|\phi\rangle$
3. It also comes with a *projection* $|\psi\rangle\langle \psi | $, which projects other physical states onto your state. E.g. acting on $|\phi\rangle$ by the projector gives $|\phi\rangle \to \langle \psi |\phi\rangle |\psi\rangle $
4. $\langle\psi|\psi\rangle = 1$, because we like states to be normalised!

Hope that aids intuition. In more advanced treatments and for quantum computing, the projection, (3), is often the best way to get a handle on what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

A state $|\psi\rangle$ in quantum mechanics is a piece of information about a system that can be copied. $|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$  and $\langle\psi|$ are both best understood as alternate representations of that same state. And $\langle\psi|\psi\rangle$ is a complex number such that $|\langle\psi|\psi\rangle|^2$ is the probability of the state $|\psi\rangle$ when the system is in the state $|\psi\rangle$, and $|\psi\rangle$ is often normalised so that $|\langle\psi|\psi\rangle|^2 =1$.

Part of the problem with your question is that it puts the cart before the horse. You need to have a rough idea of what the appropriate explanation is before the maths will make much sense. If you want to understand quantum mechanics in greater depth, then read papers like http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.3245 and http://xxx.lanl.gov/abs/quant-ph/0104033 and lectures like http://www.quiprocone.org/Protected/DD_lectures.htm.

Comment: What does your first sentence mean (consider the no-cloning theorem)?

Comment: @JosGibbons You can represent the state by a projector or a density, so it is a representation of a state.

Comment: @sunspots: It is perfectly possible to copy a particular state, such as $|\psi\rangle$: the no-cloning theorem does not prohibit this. Trivial example $U = |\psi\rangle\langle\psi|+P$ where $P$ is a sum of projectors onto states orthogonal to $|\psi\rangle$. The operation that copies $|\psi\rangle$ will not copy other states that are superpositions of $|\psi\rangle$ with something else: hence the no-cloning theorem.

Comment: With respect to your choice of $U$ in the comments, I agree with your statement. But the usage of "copy" seems misleading without a definition in your answer.